# Unknown pod name

Tags: cocoapods, appcode

In AppCode, via CocoaPods, I am trying to install the pod **QuickDialog**
In the Podfile, I have:
`pod "QuickDialog"`
When I go to install, I get an error saying **Unknown pod name**
The Message window shows:
*/usr/bin/ruby /Applications/AppCode.app/Contents/bin/pod install --no-ansi

Updating local specs repositories

Failed with exit code: -1*

What do I need to do?

Edit: Also tried suggestion by I'L'I:

```
pod 'QuickDialog', '~1.0'
```

Comment: Maybe try: `pod 'QuickDialog', '~>1.0'`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the results is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try on a new project:

1. Xcode > New > Project > Single View App > Obj-C > SO-32098667 > Next > Create
2. Terminal > cd ../SO-32098667/
3. pod init
4. Use the Podfile below
5. pod install

**Podfile**

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'SO-32098667' do
pod 'QuickDialog'
end
```

**pod install**

```
Downloading dependencies
Installing QuickDialog (1.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

Tested minutes ago with `pod` version 0.37.1 `Xcode` version 6.4.

Comment: This works, thanks. Some notes to future readers:  

When you do the 'pod install' command, you may get an error saying pod:command not found, in which case you need to do 'sudo gem install cocoapods'    When you get to where it says "Updating local specs repositories", this takes a long time (25 minutes in my case)
and there is no progress indicator.